# Optimize if/else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, optimization

I wrote the following code to simulate and simplify what is happening in my application.

In this simplification, I have the if and else branch that are executing the same code

```js
async function manipulDom(e) {
  const URItwo = `https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`;
  let response = await fetch(URItwo);
  var data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  for (var key in data) {
    if (data[key].cc == "USD") {
      rateone.innerHTML =
        data[key].txt + ` ` + data[key].rate.toFixed(2) + `грн`;
      cursUSD = data[key].rate.toFixed(2);
      console.log(cursUSD);
    } else if (data[key].cc == "EUR") {
      ratetwo.innerHTML =
        data[key].txt + ` ` + data[key].rate.toFixed(2) + `грн`;
      cursEUR = data[key].rate.toFixed(2);
      console.log(cursEUR);
    } else if (data[key].cc == "PLN") {
      ratetree.innerHTML =
        data[key].txt + ` ` + data[key].rate.toFixed(2) + `грн`;
      cursPLN = data[key].rate.toFixed(2);
      console.log(cursPLN);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are `cursUSD`, `cursEUR` and `cursPLN` declared? Please `"use strict"`. Also, are you deliberately breaking the loop early when `PLN` comes up, or is it a typo?

Comment: Use ternary operator instead of if-else statement. Refer below link:
https://www.thoughtco.com/javascript-by-example-use-of-the-ternary-operator-2037394

Comment: @Amadan They are not declared anywhere.But this variables needs in In other functions

Comment: Under strict JavaScript, that's an error. This helps you catch a lot of errors you otherwise wouldn't. It's a better practice to either not have global variables, or if you really have to, explicitly reference them from `window`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use objects indexed by the currency abbreviations instead:

```
const cursObj = {
  USD: <value of cursUSD>,
  EUR: <value of cursEUR>,
  PLN: <value of cursPLN>
};
const rateElementsByCurrency = {
  USD: rateone,
  EUR: rateTwo,
  PLN: rateThree
}

async function manipulDom(e) {
  const URItwo = `https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`;
  const response = await fetch(URItwo);
  const data = await response.json();
  data.forEach((obj) => {
    const { cc } = obj;
    if (cursObj[cc]) {
      cursObj[cc] = obj.rate.toFixed(2);
      rateElementsByCurrency[cc].textContent = obj.txt + ` ` + cursObj[cc] + `грн`;
      // If you're familiar with template literals, then you can do instead:
      // rateElementsByCurrency[cc].textContent = `${obj.txt} ${cursObj[cc]}грн`;
    }
  });
}
```

Because `data` is an [array](https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json), not an object, iterate over it with `forEach` - don't use `[for..in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) to iterate over arrays.

Because you want to put *text* into the `rateElementsByCurrency` elements, rather than HTML, you should use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, it's safer, quicker, and more predictable.

Comment: More elegant and complete than mine

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
async function manipulDom(e) {
  const URItwo = `https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`;
  const response = await fetch(URItwo);
  const data = await response.json();
  var cc = ["USD", "EUR", "PLN"];
  var exchangeRates = {};  
  for(value of data){
      if(cc.includes(value.cc)){
          let index = cc.indexOf(value.cc);
          cc.splice(index,index+1);
          value.rate = Number(value.rate).toFixed(2);
          exchangeRates[value.cc] = value;  
      }
      if(cc.length < 1){break;}

  }
  console.log(exchangeRates);
}
manipulDom();
```